# writing query in cake php

Tags: mysql, cakephp

how to write the following query in cakephp 2.0 syntax

```
SELECT `customers`.*
FROM `group_customers`, `customers`
WHERE 
`group_customers`.`customer_id`=`customers`.`id`
AND `group_customers`.`group_id`=7
AND
(`customers`.`name` LIKE 'O%' OR `customers`.`company` LIKE 'O%')
```

where customers and group_customers are two table and have the Customer and Groupcustomer model

plz help me to get the proper cakephp syntax as i tried using in the following way

```
this->Customer->find('all',array(
                'joins' => array(
                array(
                'table' => 'group_customers',
                'alias' => 'GroupCustomer',
                'type' => 'INNER',
                'conditions' => array(
                'GroupCustomer.customer_id'=>'Customer.id',
                'GroupCustomer.group_id'=>$grpid ))),
                'conditions' => array('OR'=>array('Customer.name LIKE'
                                 =>$text.'%','Customer.company LIKE'=>$text.'%'))
                    ));
```

Comment: And what is the SQL that is generated by your `find`?

Comment: getting a blank array

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code.

Join the group_customers with customers

```
$this->GroupCustomer->bindModel(
    array(
        'belongsTo' => array(
            'Customer' => array(
                'className' => 'Customer',
                'foreignKey' => 'customer_id'
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Fetch the GroupCustomer and Customer records

```
$this->GroupCustomer->find(
    'all',
    array(
        'GroupCustomer.group_id' => 7,
        'OR' => array(
            'Customer.name LIKE' => '0%'
            'Customer.company LIKE' => '0%'
        )
    )
);
```

Thanks..!